# Upgrade from WS remote to WSS not working mixed content warning

Tags: nginx, websocket

I have a solar panel control panel in my house, this runs on some linux distro. It serves a html5/js webpage over HTTP. (No way to setup SSL on this host)

I want to proxy this with NGINX (different host) to be able to access it all via HTTPS for intergration with other home automation systems.

The (lets call it Venus) device is using port 80 (HTTP), 81 (websockify VNC, not a priority but nice to have), 7890 (ws://) and 9001 (ws://)

I have setup nginx (as far as i know) to also listen on those ports as the webpage data ports are hardcoded in the config (to get info readings on the system, it tries to get them from localhost so i pass them from nginx to venus)

I've spend over 4 days searching, trying config etc. In the code below when i uncomment SSL and the SSL certs i can connect via HTTP.

Full config here: https://pastebin.com/fgwgsTnF
Inside http config:

```
   upstream websockets {
    server VENUS-IP:9001;
    server VENUS-IP:7890;

    check interval=3000 rise=2 fall=5 timeout=1000;
   }

   server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    server_name nginx.localdomain.nl;

    ssl_certificate /usr/local/etc/nginx/certs/cert.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /usr/local/etc/nginx/certs/cert.key;
    ssl_session_timeout 1d;
    ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:50m;
    ssl_session_tickets off;

    ssl_protocols TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers 'ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256';
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    add_header Strict-Transport-Security max-age=15768000;

    location /app {

      proxy_set_header        Host $host;
      proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

      proxy_pass          http://VENUS-IP;
      proxy_read_timeout  90;

      proxy_redirect      http://VENUS-IP https://nginx.localdomain.nl;
    }     

    server {
        server_name nginx.localdomain.nl;
        listen 9001; # ssl;

        #ssl_certificate /usr/local/etc/nginx/certs/cert.crt;
        #ssl_certificate_key /usr/local/etc/nginx/certs/cert.key;

        location / {
            # redirect all HTTP traffic
            proxy_pass http://websockets;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

            # WebSocket support
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";             
        }
    }

    server {
        server_name nginx.localdomain.nl;
        listen 81 ssl;

        ssl_certificate /usr/local/etc/nginx/certs/cert.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /usr/local/etc/nginx/certs/cert.key;

        location /websockify {
        websockify_pass websockets;
        }
    }  
}
```

I can properly proxy everything on HTTP, but as soon as i try to serve the WS over HTTPS it fails with a mixed content warning. I've tried a dozen combinations but they all fail.

https://community.victronenergy.com/storage/attachments/3384-1559169860907.png

Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

Could be that the content of the webpage has the URL of the websocket pointed to the insecure URI? 
Maybe you should try to configure NGINX to change that URI when proxy the page. 
I find this article of NGINX -> https://www.nginx.com/blog/websocket-nginx/

In the comments some guy Dimitry ask for something like this, and the response is:

---

Is it possible to proxy WSS (WebSocket secure: WS over TLS) with nginx?
−
    Yes it works,

```
    location / {
    proxy_set_header HOST $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_pass_request_headers on;
    proxy_pass http://<server ip="">:<server port="">;
    proxy_http_version 1.0;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
    }
```

---

Check the config adding the lines **proxy_pass_request_headers** and **proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto**.
If this doesn't work, maybe you should try using a rewrite sentence ( https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html ).

Regards